# Perl: print certain rows based on certain values of column

Tags: perl

Hey guys im begginer in Perl programming ,on my list.txt i have a 5 row and 7 columns what i want to do is print certain rows based on the value that the column have for example:

```
NO. RES REF ERRORS  WARNING PROB_E  PROB_C
1   k   C   0       0      0.240    0.713     
2   l   C   16      2      0.365    0.568     
3   n   C   7       4      0.365    0.568     
4   f   E   0       0      0.613    0.342
```

I want to print from the column 3,4(error and warnings ) all the rows that have value different than 0. In this case the output to is the row 2 and 3.I hope i make myself clear :) sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What have you tried? Other than coming here and asking "plz gib teh codez".

Comment: of couse i tried and i found a way not so cleaver but here it is.  while ($line=<FILE>) {
@parola = split ' ', $line;
 print " $line" if (($parola[16]!=0) && ($parola[18]!=0));

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
perl -ane 'print if ($F[3] or $F[4])' list.txt
```